# How to integrate "flow" in webstorm?

Tags: webstorm, flowtype

I am using WebStorm IDE. I need to know how to integrate flow with WebStorm.

I tried the steps given in this [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/09/webstorm-11-eap-142-5255/), but it is not showing hints or errors.

Comment: I performed the same steps and it works for me.

Comment: all you need to do to enable Flow support is setting javaScript language version accordingly (http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/09/webstorm-11-eap-142-5255/). If this doesn't work for you, I'd suggest creating a support ticket

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flow in JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916152/flow-in-jetbrains-intellij-idea)

Answer (score -1):

I've put together an experimental plugin integrating Flow error reports into IDEA/WebStorm as error annotations:

https://github.com/dsilva/webstorm-plugin-flow-typecheck/releases

See also [Flow in JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916152/flow-in-jetbrains-intellij-idea/38880157)