# Flow in JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, flowtype

It seems like JetBrains [supports](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/using-the-flow-type-checker.html) [Flow type checker](http://flowtype.org) but I'm not seeing the flow error in the IDE.

Is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 3):

Flow Type Checker is not yet supported, please follow [WEB-14254](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14254) for updates. 
Idea just supports Flow syntax (static typing). See http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/09/webstorm-11-eap-142-5255/

Answer (score 2):

I've put together an experimental plugin integrating Flow error reports into IDEA/WebStorm as error annotations:

https://github.com/dsilva/webstorm-plugin-flow-typecheck/releases

Comment: This plugin works very well for me right now. Here's a detailed article that describes how I use it in my react webapp: http://www.davidtanzer.net/spring_boot_and_react_flow_and_mocha

Answer (score 0):

@lena is correct.

As an aside, I run flow through the `npm` panel.  As long as `flow` is a script in your `package.json`, I run in by right-clicking on `package.json` and `Show npm scripts`.   Then just double click on `flow` or re-run it as needed in the `Run` panel.

Answer (score 0):

As of Nov 2016 Jetbrains Webstorm / IntelliJ IDEA now supports Flow:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/11/using-flow-in-webstorm/

In Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript select Flow

Answer (score 0):

## Running Flow Server in WebStorm

---

#### check the version of your flow-bin, only 0.59.0 works with WebStorm.

---

- run this command to install flow-bin globally:

> npm i -g flow-bin@0.59.0

- Adding flow config file to your project

> npm flow init

- finding node-modules global path : copy this path , We will use it in WebStorm settings.

> npm list -g

---

### WebStorm Setting :

1. Go to here :

> File > Settings > languages and Frameworks > Javascript

- Select **flow** in drop-down menu.
- In **Flow executable** paste global path of flow-bin (local path doesn't work). and with three dots button select the proper folder for your operating system.
- In Use-Flow-server-for section tick **Type checking** box and then hit Apply button.

---

2. Find this section in settings :

   > Editor > Inspections > Javascript > Flow Type Checker

ensure **Flow errors** check box is active
Hit Apply and Ok
After that flow server should be started when you open project in Webstorm.
Don't forget to put

> *// @flow*

at top of your files.